# oder einem Nomen

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronominal-adverb

> Die Pronominaladverbien haben eine Stellung zwischen den Adverbien und den Pronomen. Da sie für die Verbindung einer Präposition mit einem Pronomen **oder einem Nomen** stehen, werden sie hier bei den Pronomen beschrieben.

In my knowledge Pronominaladverbien is a combination of adverb and preposition, Here I do not understand why they include **"einem Nomen"**

https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wort/Pronomen/FRegeln-P/PronAdv/index.html?lang=de#id=1.5.1.8

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich sorry  I have updated the link now

Answer (score 2):

I assume they just want to express that a Pronominaladverb has itself a pronoun-like function, and in some cases, it replaces what would otherwise have been expressed as a pronoun that itself has replaced a noun.

> Ich war voriges Jahr auf einem Konzert.  Ich erinnere mich gut daran.

Theoretically, both of the following sentences are equivalent to the second one:

> - Ich erinnere mich gut an es.
> - Ich erinnere mich gut an das Konzert.

This is a transitive relation, somehow: *an das Konzert* ~> *an es* ~> *daran*.  However, while all variants have the same denotation, the one repeating *das Konzert* sounds weird in this context, because it does not refer to already given information by a pronoun.  (That is unidiomatic information structure.)

(*Ich erinnere mich gut an es* also sounds somewhat unidiomatic, but only because the *daran* form is blocking it; it's not "wrongly" information structured.)

There are other cases where the replacement is not appearent:

> Ich erinnere mich gut daran, dass dort XYZ gespielt hat.

Here we could theoretically make up an elliptic *an die Tatsache, dass*, but this "hidden phrase" has conversational function, similar to an impersonal *es*, and is not directly referring to a previous piece of syntax, but to an implied conception of the context given indirectly by previous information.  (Or alternatively, you can interpret it as a refererence to the following sentence *dass dort XYZ gespielt hat*, but that's also not simply a noun.)